# ReactJs - Justify Sidebar

Tags: reactjs, sidebar

I'm new to ReactJS and i want to open sidebar from right.

All tutorials just teach how we can open sidebar from left with little hamburger icon but I can't find how it can be opened from right.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Made this for you - opens from right :)

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mqp5m4pqzx